# Пример стратегии на PHP

Tags: php, шаблоны-проектирования, рефакторинг, шаблон-стратегия

Здесь приведён пример стратегии на PHP: https://refactoring.guru/ru/design-patterns/strategy/php/example#example-1

Вопрос в следующем: Почему в этом примере нет класса, хранящего ссылку на класс стратегию (на класс, реализующий PaymentMethod), как это описано в этом же разделе? Правильная ли это реализация данного паттерна?

Answer (score 1):

Пример честно говоря запутанный и неудачный. Там реализация сразу и фабрики, и стратегии. Посмотрите лучше на другом ресурсе другие реализации этого паттерна.

Причем как я понял обе стратегии не используются.

В чем там алгоритм:

1) Смотрите на метод get контроллера, а нем происходит работа роутера - по регулярному выражению находится метод оплаты:

```
$controller->get("/order/1/payment/paypal"); - это стратегия для пайпала
$controller->get("/order/1/payment/сс"); - это стратегия для карты (в примере почему то этого нет)
```

2) Дальше идет поиск метода оплаты:

```
preg_match('#^/order/([0-9]+?)/payment/([a-z]+?)(/return)?$#', $path, $matches)
// Способ оплаты (стратегия) выбирается в соответствии со значением,
// переданным в запросе.
$paymentMethod = PaymentFactory::getPaymentMethod($matches[2]); 

$matches[2] будет равно или 'paypal' или 'cc'

$paymentMethod - это как раз реализация PaymentMethod interface
```